# serverless: configure deadletter SQS queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, serverless

I use serverless to configure a Lambda function that receives events via AWS SQS. Now I want to add a dead letter queue. That's what I have so far:

```yaml
service: myservice

plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-lambda-dead-letter

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: go1.x
  region: eu-central-1
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "sqs:*"
      Resource:
        - "*"

package:
 exclude:
   - ./**
 include:
   - ./bin/**

functions:
  main:
    handler: bin/send-mail
    deadLetter:
      sqs:
        queueName: send-mail-dlx
        messageRetentionPeriod: 200000
    events:
      - sqs: arn:aws:sqs:eu-central-1:123456789:send-mail
```

Both SQS queues were created successfully, but the dead letter queue `send-mail-dlx` isn't assigned as dead letter queue to `send-mail`. How do I assign it properly in my serverless config?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it: https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/4647#issuecomment-474306379

```yaml
resources:
  Resources:
    MyQueue:
      Type: "AWS::SQS::Queue"
      Properties:
        QueueName: "MyQueue"
        VisibilityTimeout: 30
        MessageRetentionPeriod: 60
        RedrivePolicy:
          deadLetterTargetArn:
            "Fn::GetAtt":
              - ReceiverDeadLetterQueue
              - Arn
          maxReceiveCount: 1
    ReceiverDeadLetterQueue:
      Type: "AWS::SQS::Queue"
      Properties:
        QueueName: "receiverDLQ"
        MessageRetentionPeriod: 1209600 # 14 days in seconds
```